# How the query works?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not understanding how a query in an example works. The query is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE... 
    GROUP BY Table1.column2, Table1. Column3
)
```

Do you know how this query works in practically, particularly the select count (1) and select 1?

Comment: This is called a [`subquery`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-subquery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have here 2 queries, a inner one and an outer one. The inner one:

```
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE... 
    GROUP BY Table1.column2, Table1. Column3
```

will get you some result as a normal query, the outer one will count how many rows you get as a result, `COUNT(1)` acts the same way as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thanks, so the inner query is always executed first and then the outer? And can you explain the select? The select is to select the columns we want to get right? If it's 1 I'm not understanding how it works.

Comment: Yes, that's the logic, first inner, then outer over inner result. `SELECT 1` will return 1 per each valid result, but you are discarding it with the outer query

Answer (score 2):

`Count(1)` and `Count(*)` are interchangeable.  "Select all"

The `subquery` as Sterling mentioned is Grouped.  So the resulting query should output the total count of groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Inner query will select '1' so many times as many rows you will get after applying of filtering and grouping.
After that outer query will counts all the lines in the inner query. (count(1) is equal to count(*))
The result is count of groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT *  FROM table1(
    WHERE... 
    GROUP BY Table1.column2, Table1. Column3
);
```

Comment: I have a doubt on syntax.

Comment: this query returns the number of rows that matches in that thable with count and the * refeers to all the columns on the table.

Comment: what about `(` after table1?

Comment: WHERE is a condition and GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows.

Comment: I meant both those brackets are useless.